# Contains() runs much slower than .Any in this case, why?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

The following 3 example codes are identical except for tiny differences, which is commented by Look at here. However the speed differs much.

Sample 1: It runs 59 sec in my computer.

```
namespace AoDtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool IsWin(IList<string[]> slotView)
        {
            string[] symbol = new string[3];
            for (int reelID = 0; reelID < 3; reelID++)
            {
                symbol[reelID] = slotView[reelID][1];
            }
            if (symbol.Contains("B")) return true; // Look at here
            // if (symbol.Any(x => x == "B")) return true;
            return false;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            int count = 0;
            string reel1 = "J   K   10  S   R   10  K   Q   10  A   Q   K   10  Q   K   R   10  K   R   10  J   R   10  A   Q   R   A   10  J   Q   10  R   K   10  L   S   A   L   10  Q   A   S   Q   A   R   10  K   R   L   10  R   A   S   10  L   Q   A   L   10  S   R   10  Q";
            string reel2 = "L   K   J   B   A   10  Q   L   R   Q   J   L   Q   R   J   Q   10  J   R   L   Q   J   10  B   Q   K   10  L   Q   J   S   Q   10  L   A   Q   L   J   R   Q   10  S   A   10  Q   B   J   A   L   S   K   Q   S   J   10  Q   L   S   Q   L   K   10  R";
            string reel3 = "J   S   A   J   B   Q   K   J   S   2x  R   Q   S   J   R   L   J   S   K   L   J   K   L   S   J   10  B   K   Q   S   J   K   L   A   K   J   A   K   S   10  J   A   R   2x  L   K   J   A   B   K   J   R   K   J   A   K   J   A   L   R   J   K   R";
            string[] myreel1 = reel1.Split('\t');
            string[] myreel2 = reel2.Split('\t');
            string[] myreel3 = reel3.Split('\t');
            for (int n = 0; n < 200; n++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < myreel1.Length; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < myreel2.Length; j++)
                        for (int k = 0; k < myreel3.Length; k++)
                        {
                            string[][] slotView = new string[3][];
                            for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
                            {
                                slotView[m] = new string[2];
                            }
                            slotView[0][1] = myreel1[i];
                            slotView[1][1] = myreel2[j];
                            slotView[2][1] = myreel3[k];

                            if (IsWin(slotView)) count++;
                        }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.WriteLine((double)reel1.Length * reel2.Length * reel3.Length / count);
            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample 2: It runes 20 sec in my computer.

```
namespace AoDtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool IsWin(IList<string[]> slotView)
        {
            string[] symbol = new string[3];
            for (int reelID = 0; reelID < 3; reelID++)
            {
                symbol[reelID] = slotView[reelID][1];
            }
            // if (symbol.Contains("B")) return true;
            if (symbol.Any(x => x == "B")) return true; // Look at here  
            return false;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            int count = 0;
            string reel1 = "J   K   10  S   R   10  K   Q   10  A   Q   K   10  Q   K   R   10  K   R   10  J   R   10  A   Q   R   A   10  J   Q   10  R   K   10  L   S   A   L   10  Q   A   S   Q   A   R   10  K   R   L   10  R   A   S   10  L   Q   A   L   10  S   R   10  Q";
            string reel2 = "L   K   J   B   A   10  Q   L   R   Q   J   L   Q   R   J   Q   10  J   R   L   Q   J   10  B   Q   K   10  L   Q   J   S   Q   10  L   A   Q   L   J   R   Q   10  S   A   10  Q   B   J   A   L   S   K   Q   S   J   10  Q   L   S   Q   L   K   10  R";
            string reel3 = "J   S   A   J   B   Q   K   J   S   2x  R   Q   S   J   R   L   J   S   K   L   J   K   L   S   J   10  B   K   Q   S   J   K   L   A   K   J   A   K   S   10  J   A   R   2x  L   K   J   A   B   K   J   R   K   J   A   K   J   A   L   R   J   K   R";
            string[] myreel1 = reel1.Split('\t');
            string[] myreel2 = reel2.Split('\t');
            string[] myreel3 = reel3.Split('\t');
            for (int n = 0; n < 200; n++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < myreel1.Length; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < myreel2.Length; j++)
                        for (int k = 0; k < myreel3.Length; k++)
                        {
                            string[][] slotView = new string[3][];
                            for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
                            {
                                slotView[m] = new string[2];
                            }
                            slotView[0][1] = myreel1[i];
                            slotView[1][1] = myreel2[j];
                            slotView[2][1] = myreel3[k];

                            if (IsWin(slotView)) count++;
                        }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.WriteLine((double)reel1.Length * reel2.Length * reel3.Length / count);
            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample 3: Now I use `Contains()` again, but move some code from `IsWin` into `Main`, It runs 14 sec now, why it is faster here?

**Big Discovery: `IList<string> symbol` if I switch to `string[] symbol`  then it runs 57 secs.**

```
namespace AoDtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool IsWin(IList<string> symbol)
        {
            if (symbol.Contains("B")) return true;
            // if (symbol.Any(x => x == "B")) return true;
            return false;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            int count = 0;
            string reel1 = "J   K   10  S   R   10  K   Q   10  A   Q   K   10  Q   K   R   10  K   R   10  J   R   10  A   Q   R   A   10  J   Q   10  R   K   10  L   S   A   L   10  Q   A   S   Q   A   R   10  K   R   L   10  R   A   S   10  L   Q   A   L   10  S   R   10  Q";
            string reel2 = "L   K   J   B   A   10  Q   L   R   Q   J   L   Q   R   J   Q   10  J   R   L   Q   J   10  B   Q   K   10  L   Q   J   S   Q   10  L   A   Q   L   J   R   Q   10  S   A   10  Q   B   J   A   L   S   K   Q   S   J   10  Q   L   S   Q   L   K   10  R";
            string reel3 = "J   S   A   J   B   Q   K   J   S   2x  R   Q   S   J   R   L   J   S   K   L   J   K   L   S   J   10  B   K   Q   S   J   K   L   A   K   J   A   K   S   10  J   A   R   2x  L   K   J   A   B   K   J   R   K   J   A   K   J   A   L   R   J   K   R";
            string[] myreel1 = reel1.Split('\t');
            string[] myreel2 = reel2.Split('\t');
            string[] myreel3 = reel3.Split('\t');
            for (int n = 0; n < 200; n++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < myreel1.Length; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < myreel2.Length; j++)
                        for (int k = 0; k < myreel3.Length; k++)
                        {
                            string[][] slotView = new string[3][];
                            for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
                            {
                                slotView[m] = new string[2];
                            }
                            slotView[0][1] = myreel1[i];
                            slotView[1][1] = myreel2[j];
                            slotView[2][1] = myreel3[k];

                            string[] symbol = new string[3];
                            for (int reelID = 0; reelID < 3; reelID++)
                            {
                                symbol[reelID] = slotView[reelID][1]; // Look at here
                            }

                            if (IsWin(symbol))
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.WriteLine((double)reel1.Length * reel2.Length * reel3.Length / count);
            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample 4: Similar to Sample 3, but use `Any` instead, runs 17 sec.
**Big Discovery: `IList<string> symbol` if I switch to `string[] symbol`  then it runs  18 secs.**

```
namespace AoDtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool IsWin(IList<string> symbol)
        {
            if (symbol.Contains("B")) return true;
            // if (symbol.Any(x => x == "B")) return true;
            return false;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            int count = 0;
            string reel1 = "J   K   10  S   R   10  K   Q   10  A   Q   K   10  Q   K   R   10  K   R   10  J   R   10  A   Q   R   A   10  J   Q   10  R   K   10  L   S   A   L   10  Q   A   S   Q   A   R   10  K   R   L   10  R   A   S   10  L   Q   A   L   10  S   R   10  Q";
            string reel2 = "L   K   J   B   A   10  Q   L   R   Q   J   L   Q   R   J   Q   10  J   R   L   Q   J   10  B   Q   K   10  L   Q   J   S   Q   10  L   A   Q   L   J   R   Q   10  S   A   10  Q   B   J   A   L   S   K   Q   S   J   10  Q   L   S   Q   L   K   10  R";
            string reel3 = "J   S   A   J   B   Q   K   J   S   2x  R   Q   S   J   R   L   J   S   K   L   J   K   L   S   J   10  B   K   Q   S   J   K   L   A   K   J   A   K   S   10  J   A   R   2x  L   K   J   A   B   K   J   R   K   J   A   K   J   A   L   R   J   K   R";
            string[] myreel1 = reel1.Split('\t');
            string[] myreel2 = reel2.Split('\t');
            string[] myreel3 = reel3.Split('\t');
            for (int n = 0; n < 200; n++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < myreel1.Length; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < myreel2.Length; j++)
                        for (int k = 0; k < myreel3.Length; k++)
                        {
                            string[][] slotView = new string[3][];
                            for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++)
                            {
                                slotView[m] = new string[2];
                            }
                            slotView[0][1] = myreel1[i];
                            slotView[1][1] = myreel2[j];
                            slotView[2][1] = myreel3[k];

                            string[] symbol = new string[3];
                            for (int reelID = 0; reelID < 3; reelID++)
                            {
                                symbol[reelID] = slotView[reelID][1]; // Look at here
                            }

                            if (IsWin(symbol))
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.WriteLine((double)reel1.Length * reel2.Length * reel3.Length / count);
            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're only timing one run of each algorithm. Run them 10,000 times and then compare the times.

Comment: You should really make a smaller sample to test this

Comment: That's not "much" slower anyway. It's not even an order of magnitude!

Comment: Also, this isn't exactly what you'd call a 'minimal' example, and thus not too handy for testing.

Comment: @ChrisF: Did u see i have looped it 20 times in each case? Also it integrates the reels loop which equals 63*63*63= 250000 loops, overall it exceeds 5M loops.

Comment: It wasn't clear that the loop of 20 wasn't part of the algorithm, I would have expected a bigger value.

Comment: You're not using the `Contains` extension method on `IEnumerable` but the `Collection<T>.Contains` method here. So your topic is wrong. On the other hand `string[].Contains` should be even faster than the extension method.

Comment: Hmm perhaps it's because `s1==s2` is faster than `EqualityComperer<string>.Default.Equals(s1,s2)`

Comment: @CodeInChaos: OkOk, whatever, even the topic is wrong, I cannot see any reason why my 3 examples differ in speed.

Comment: MeasureIt is a handy tool for measuring stuff like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507639.aspx

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Hey, big discovery, it turned out that my topic becomes correct somehow.. as I figured out that indeed it is in fact relating to the issue that `IEnumerable.Contains` runs much slower than `IEnumerable.Any`, because `ICollection.Contains` in my test gives similar performance as `IEnumerable.Any`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather interesting.

Documentation for `IEnumerable<T>.Contains` says that if the source parameter implements `ICollection<T>`, then it calls `ICollection<T>.Contains`. And since `string[]` implements `ICollection<string>`, that's what gets called.

The `Array` implementation of `ICollection<T>.Contains` ends up calling `Array.IndexOf`.

If you change your code to read:

```
if (Array.IndexOf(symbol, "B"))
```

It executes as fast as `Any`. Same if you change the code to:

```
if ((symbol as ICollection<string>).Contains("B"))
```

In my tests, calling `Array.IndexOf` is twice as fast as calling `symbol.Contains`.

I suspect what's slowing things down is that `IEnumerable<T>.Contains` has to decide with each call whether it will call `ICollection<T>.Contains`, or do something else. That decision doesn't have to be made when `Any` is called.

You can replace all the code in `IsWin` with this, which is faster still than either of the above, and is a whole lot simpler.

```
static bool IsWin(IList<string[]> slotView)
{
    return slotView.Any(s => s[1] == "B");
}
```

Then, of course, you can just get rid of the `IsWin` method altogether and write in your inner loop:

```
if (slotView.Any(s => s[1] == "B")
    ++count;
```

Comment: 1. Yes `.IndexOf` gives me 16sec, faster than any of the three 2. I cannot eliminate `IsWin` function as in reality there will be more stuff in the function than this simplified version.

Comment: Also, I have done some tests.  `if ((symbol.Contains("B"))` 55 sec;   `if ((symbol as IEnumerable<string>).Contains("B"))` 55 sec; `if ((symbol as IList<string>).Contains("B"))` 14 sec; `if ((symbol as ICollection<string>).Contains("B"))` 14 sec;

Answer (score 1):

The method "Contains" does checks before applying equality operator (==). As you are running the loop several times, this checks are repeated for the loop count. 
In case of 'Any', you've already determined to use == so .Any is fast.
see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407.aspx

In 3rd case, the compiler must be optimizing the code not to make a method call (instead write the check in if condition).

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring how long it takes for the JIT compiler to compile the IsWin() method.  Which is why it makes such a big difference when you move code into Main(), the Main method gets jitted *before* you start your stopwatch.

Make your measurement more meaningful by repeating the body of your test at least 10 times so you can eliminated jit and caching effects.  Which in itself is a bit dangerous, your actual code will of course see those effects as well.

Comment: it is running 200 times, each time has a 63*63*63= 250000 loop.

Comment: I got trivial execution times testing that code.  I didn't bother trying to find out what was wrong with the logic, too much, the first loop time made it obvious that it was measuring the jitter time.

Comment: i should point out: u make trivial time because html convert the `\t` to space. this is the only thing that make copied code behave strange i guess.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing this out.  Can we get a *real* post snippet please?